# Can the question "How do critical hits and misses work in Illyriad?" be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, undelete-request

The Community user deleted this question:
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62320/how-do-critical-hits-and-misses-work-in-illyriad
on the grounds that it is an "abandoned question".  I don't think this is fair: the question is tricky but interesting and I have some hope that eventually someone can answer it.  Can somebody undelete the question?

Comment: If [Community deleted it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year), it must have had a <=0 score, no comments, and low views for a long time, on top of having no answer, meaning the Gaming community *didn't* find the question very interesting.

Comment: In the 4 years since that question was asked, it was viewed only 103 times.  If and when the question is reopened (or re-posted) I suggest applying a reputation bounty to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as has already been pointed out, [Community automatically deletes old posts with a low score and no activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year). The deletion has been reversed,  however I doubt your question is going to get an answer, since [illyriad](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illyriad) doesn't appear to be all that popular on the site, and your question is four years old. There a few things you can do to try and get an answer though:

1. [**Set a Bounty**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties): A small bounty will push your question into the Featured tab, which will draw more attention to it. Given how few users seem to play the game on the site I'm doubtful this will work, but it's worth a shot. Never know whose poking around the Featured tab.
2. **Improve your Question:** I'm not familiar with the game, so I can't offer any specific pointers, but take a look through your question to see if there's anything you can do to improve it. Are there any more details you could add? Is there anything about your question which may make it unclear? Improving your question may it easier for folks to answer, or make folks more willing to answer it if they think you put a lot of work into your question.
3. **Try to figure out the answer yourself:** The questions four years old now, so it's entirely possible someone has already figured this out, and some Googling will give you the answer. If not, you could try experimenting in game to figure out  an answer, although I'm not sure how hard it would be to do so. Either way, if you find an answer, then you should [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), so future visitors to the site will be able to benefit from any research or experimentation you did.

Comment: Viewing the revision history of the question, OP has set a 50 rep bounty in the past.